# Drag and Drop the images on canvas using jqueryui

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

> I have completed the dragging and dropping  of **buttons** and **nav bar** and it is draggable after drop also and working properly,
>
> But now  problem is now i want to drag and drop the **image**.i have tried many different things but unable to do this.

```
I am adding my fiddle please check
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yousuf_007/d6gowym5/

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I'm now working on a project similar to yours, but in the left div I have a list and every draggable element is a list item. This function works perfect for me, maybe it will be useful for you:

```
        $('#streams li').draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
        //Function for setting drag and drop settings
        function foo(){
            $('.foo').each(function() {
                //Making dropped elements draggable again
                $('.foo').draggable({
                    containment: $(this).parent(),
                    stack: '.foo',
                    snap: '.foo',
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
                        alert("nodeid: " + ui.draggable.data("noteid") + 
                            ", Top: " + (pos.top - dPos.top) + 
                            ", Left: " + (pos.left - dPos.left));
                    },
                    drag: function(){
                        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
                        $(this).css({'z-index': '11'});
                        $(".class"+draggedItemId).css({'z-index':'15'});
                    },
                    stop: function(){
                        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
                        $(this).css({'z-index': '0'});
                        $(".class"+draggedItemId).css({'z-index':'10'});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
        //Generating new table after drop
        $('#mainDiv').droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                //Getting position where new item was dropped
                var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
                var droppedTop = ui.position.top - $(this).offset().top;
                var droppedLeft = ui.position.left - $(this).offset().left;
                //Generating new table if the item is dropped first time
                if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
                    var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
                    var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
                    var item = $('<table class="foo small elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="'+(fooCount+1)+'" style="left: '+droppedLeft+'px; top: '+droppedTop+'px;"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass"><span class="header">' + title + '</span><span class="settings"><img src="Icons/pignon.png" width="17px" height="17px" alt="Settings" title="Settings" /></span></th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
                    $(this).append(item);
                    fooCount += 1;
                    foo();
                }
            }
        });
```

Try to rewrite your function and give it similar look. Also change your DOM structure from separate elements to list, that will help you to easily implement drag and drop. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/7gvon7h1/

**EDIT:** Here is your fiddle. I have initialized drag and drop. The rest, styling and what you do to your content while dropping is up to you: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/rhz6ovyz/

Comment: can you put a fiddle please

Comment: @Khan Done. my app is pretty big and complex, but I have only included what is needed to create DOM and initialize drag and drop.

Comment: no just edit my fiddle just put some list items change html call your class so i can see how it is working .i"ll tried but it is not working by me

Comment: @Khan I have edited your fiddle and wrote some instructions as comments. styling is up to you.